# Kernel of a map from degree $r$ forms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a finite field of order $q$. Let $P_r$ be the all the forms (in two 
variables) of degree $r$ with coefficients in $k$. And let $A_{D,N}$ be 
all the forms of degree $N$, which vanish on an effective divisor $D$
on $\mathbb{P}^1$.
Let $O_D = P_N / A_{D,N}$.

I am having trouble seeing that
for $r \geq \deg D$ and $N = rd$, $P_r$ surjects onto $O_D$ with kernel of size
$q^{r+1-\deg D}$. I would greatly appreciate if someone could 
explain this for me. Thanks!